# jquery validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to use jquery validate to validation register form. I tried a lot of solution but nothing work. It's simply form with one field because on start I want to have working validation. After pressing the button, the validation is avoided. Nothing happens even as the fields are empty

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form id="registerForm" name="registerForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="FName" name="FName"/>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btnregister" value="Register" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#btnregister").click(function () {

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#registerForm").validate({
                            rules: {
                                FName: {
                                    required: true
                                }
                            },
                            messages: {
                                FName: {
                                     required: "Required Field"
                                 }
                            }
                        });
                    })

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "AddUser",
                        data: 
                            {
                                FName: $('#FName').val(),

                            },
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert("Hello " + response.FName);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `~` in the pathname in your `<link>` and `<script>` tags. URLs must be relative to the current file, or to the root web directory.

Comment: This is added automatically. Also I tried add from URL and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form id="registerForm" name="registerForm" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="FName" name="FName"/>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btnregister" value="Register" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


 $(document).ready(function(){

                  $("#btnregister").click(function () {
                        alert("here");
                       $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                             url: "AddUser",
                             data: 
                            {
                               FName: $('#FName').val(),
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                               alert("Hello " + response.FName);
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                  alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $("#registerForm").validate({
                            rules: {
                                FName: {
                                    required: true
                                }
                            },
                            messages: {
                                FName: {
                                     required: "Required Field"
                                 }
                            }
                        });


});
```

You need some corrections in your script and the way you have included the scripts. Under  $(document).ready(function(), we have added 2 functions, button click, form validation.

Comment: Where is ajax post method? And what is it alert?

Comment: You can add it..I have removed to quickly test it in phpfiddle.

Comment: Yes but in which place? Under validation?

Comment: No, form is still avoid. ajax method must be inside register function but still dosen't work

Comment: When the button is to be validated and then execute the ajax method